# Error: channel closed at ChildProcess.target.send Nodejs

Tags: node.js, kubectl

**Error: channel closed
    at ChildProcess.target.send**

I have implemented an API which uploads the file. Whenever I upload a file and after the upload success I again make an API request to upload the file I receive  **Error 504 Gateway** and on the kubectl pod I get log Error: channel closed
    at ChildProcess.target.send

[image]

Comment: Could you be more precise and provide more information? From where to where you are sending this file? Inside cluster, to cluster, from cluster?
Please provide output of `kubectl get events`

Comment: from one cluster to other.@PjoterS

Comment: So as you are want connect from one cluster to another cluster you had to expose it. Did you do it as `Ingress` or `Service` ?